# What are the numbers of the alphabet in lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to create my first script, and I know this is pretty vague but I'm trying to make my script set my walkspeed in a game called ROBLOX and here's what I've got so far.

```
ws = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed
while true do
    if keyPress(27)==true then
        ws = 100
        wait(5)
        ws = 16
    end
end
```

Can somebody post the numbers for the alphabet? I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet.

ex: `Escape` = 27

Comment: "post the numbers for the alphabet" - Are you referring to ASCII codes? Your statement is literally nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called key codes. [Here is the list for Roblox](http://wiki.roblox.com/?title=API:Enum/KeyCode).

Comment: They are an adaption of ASCII codes. See [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ascii+chart&rlz=1C1GKLB_enAU666AU666&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=606&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrvK6srPrOAhUFpJQKHXwpDD4QsAQIGg#imgrc=2U31hF4tTw886M%3A)

Comment: Yes i know, but it is important to know the official documentation. I work with Corona SDK, for example, and keycodes are different on osx and on windows. For example, Esc is 27 on windows, but 53 on osx.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for late reply, forgot my password xP